# Javascript file type displayed as 'html' in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, http-status-code-403

I'm checking under network tab on a site. In my local host it works correctly. But I doubt the  site's hosting provider has some setting that is not fulfilled by my script file.

I get **403 - permission denied** error for all my js files in this server.
Additionally when I opened the network tab, I found the following:

```
Domain = the sites domain  
Cause = script  
Type = html
```

The site also has other plugins where the js file's Type = js and it rendered correctly(status = 200).

I suspected the server might be using old html, so I specified `type="text/javascript"` for it to be recognized as `js` file. yet it doesn't help.

This is a `joomla` site and my plugin is a system plugin. Does this has anything to do with my script?

Exact error I'm getting:

```
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /plugins/system/conversekit/assets/js/conversekit.js
on this server.<br />
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I think it is due to file access rights issue.

Comment: @MianHaseeb, how can I inform the hosting company about this?

Comment: Usually, this issue occurs when uploading file with FTP. I'd suggest to check the js file access permission and change them for all. If it does not help, you can talk to the hosting company support.